# Dropdown consisting of two divs with timeOut

Tags: jquery, timeout

All,

I am using the following code for a dropdown menu:

HTML

```
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <div id="Raphael" class="menuitem">Menu 1</div>
    <div id="Contact" class="menuitem">Menu 2</div>
    <div id="Contact" class="menuitem">Menu 3</div>
  </div>
<div id="submenu">Submenu</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  $(".menuitem").hover(
    function() {
      var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
      console.log(timeout);
      if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
      console.log(this);
      $("#submenu").slideDown('fast');
    },
    function() {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $('#submenu').animate({top: '-4px'}, 200); 
      }, this), 500));
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $('#submenu:visible').hide();
  });
```

CSS (this will be rendered via a CSS pre processor, this look a little different!):

```
.menuitem
  position relative
  line-height 25px
  height 25px
  display table-cell
  float left
  z-index 2
  top 0px
  background white
  border 1px solid black
  border-left 0px
  vertical-align middle
  padding 0px
  padding-left 20px
  padding-right 20px
  margin 0px
  cursor pointer
  cursor hand

#submenu
    position absolute
    width 100px
    height 100px
    font-size 12px
    text-align center
    border 1px solid black
    left 10px
    margin-top 0%
    top -4px
    background white
    z-index 2
```

The code works fine, except that when I hover the submenu it will disappear, while I expect it too display till I hover out of the submenu. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Make the `submenu` item be within the `menuitem` and your issue is solved.

Comment: I think you should post your CSS code too

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. Is it also possible to solve this differently, because I would like the submenu to move as a separate div.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are using `setTimeout()`? And why are you using `$.proxy()`? (There doesn't seem any point in `$.proxy()` when the function you use it on doesn't use `this` anywhere.) It might help us if you could provide a simple demo at http://jsfiddle.net.